# find a hash key for specific array-as-value

Tags: ruby

Given a hash of arrays, I need to get the key for which the first element of the array is minimal.

For instance, for:

```
h = { :a => [8,9,1], :b => [7,2,3], :c => [1,7,3] }
```

I'd like to get **:c** as result because **1** is the min of [8,7,1]

How can I do this elegantly?

Comment: @TheTinMan : nothing really showable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
h.key(h.values.min_by &:first)
```

Comment: you should also let your first (longer) solution

Comment: @JCLL Find the min value don't need to sort, so i prefer min_by.

Answer (score 0):

```
h.sort_by { |k,v| v[0] }[0][0]
# or (equivalent)
h.sort_by { |k,v| v.first }.first.first
```

By using the default array comparator, this can even be shortened to:

```
h.sort_by { |k,v| v }[0][0]
```